# How can I protect my NAS Backup system from ransomware

Tags: backup, home-networking, nas, cross-platform

I'm currently running a Windows 7 Desktop PC, a MacBook Pro and an iPhone. In my homenetwork I am allowed to backup my MacBook to the MacMini Server, which also works as media server.
However my father is not comfortable with me backing up my Windows machine on that server. Now I'm facing the question: Should I get myself an external storage to backup my windows on it or should I introduce my own backup system (a synology disk for example) to the homenetwork.
The synology disk has multiple advantages:

- Integrated Media Server to stream on the MacBook, the PC and the iPhone
- Backup of all the listed devices
- User interface to easy configure
- I could manage a shared git on the server

My only fear now is that if I catch some kind of ransomware on one of these devices, the next sync / backup will also encrypt the data on the synology disk.
If one disk would be backup and the other media there would still be affected both. 
*Is there a possibility to prevent network attached storages / backup services from beeing affected by things like ransomware / realtime encryption?*
And in the worst case: would my NAS be affected if any of the other devices in the network would catch one of these viruses if they had plex permissions to stream from my server?

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, but your NAS does not execute the programs you put on it. so as long as the malware does not have direct access to that NAS, like through a SAMBA server, you should be fine .

Comment: @MaartenOlijve So then I could roll back to an older backup or delete the file and play it back to the pc?

Comment: external drive , backup and disconnect, reconnect to sync. Backup software that stores multiples, or incraments for every change, and space enough to do that. Nas devices that are setup to have the files easily available to the computers are . . . Easily available to viruses and malwares. one way streaming , with no write permissions not.  Long before ransomware and still in existance is tagging every file different ways , delete and wipe, ransomware is just the new talked about destruction.    Will viruses find a way, they often do, can they get to a device not connected at all ?  not yet :-)

Comment: The simplest method would be to, have the volume mounted, only when a backup is running and of course have multiple (offline) copies of that backup.  OS X has ransomware by the way.  "My only fear now is that if I catch some kind of ransomware on one of these devices, the next sync / backup will also encrypt the data on the synology disk." - If the ransomware can see the NAS it will just directly encrypt it, it won't need to wait for the next "sync", ransomware encrypts every volume it can find.